# How do I nest multiple ng-if properly?

Tags: html, angular

I am facing an issue with multiple nested `ngIf` applied on `ng-template` elements in Angular.js, and I can't seem to get the perfect answer. I know workarounds but they are not optimized.

This is the code that I am trying to get running:

```
<div class="container">
    <ng-template *ngIf="booleanA;then caseA else caseB">
        <ng-template #caseA>
            <el>1</el>
            <el>2</el>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template #caseB>
            <ng-template *ngIf="booleanB">
                <el>3</el>
                <el>4</el>
                <el>5</el>
            </ng-template>
        </ng-template>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

And these are the two solutions I have found to my problem:

- Placing the ngIf on every child element inside of the `#caseB` element:

  ```
    <ng-template #caseB>
        <el *ngIf="booleanB">3</el>
        <el *ngIf="booleanB">4</el>
        <el *ngIf="booleanB">5</el>
    </ng-template>
  ```
- Placing the surrounding `class="container"` element inside both `#caseA` and `#caseB`, and applying the second `ngIf` to it:

  ```
    <ng-template *ngIf="booleanA;then caseA else caseB">
        <ng-template #caseA>
            <div class="container">
                <el>1</el>
                <el>2</el>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template #caseB>
            <div *ngIf="booleanB" class="container">
                <el>3</el>
                <el>4</el>
                <el>5</el>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </ng-template>
  ```

The issue with these solutions is in the optimization. The first one checks multiple times for the same value, and the second one uses the same HTML element twice.

Is there any way I could make the original design work?

EDIT: The two solutions wouldn't appear as blocks of code, therefore I styled them as inline code. If you know how to fix that you'd be very welcome.

EDIT 2: Bringing some clarification as to what I am looking for: The end goal is not for the code to work, I have already found workarounds that I could use if all else fails.

The end goal is to get this code working only **with** Angular's logical element `<ng-template>` and by following the original design; and **without** the help of additional native elements like `div`, which would alter the DOM.

Comment: *ngIf="a" on first and *ngIf="!a && b" on second. Don't nest them, it makes the code more complicated

Comment: if you get more cases consider using *ngSwitch with an enum instead of boolean

Comment: Yeah, but that would mean double-checking `booleanA` then, which in this case needs to be computed everytime it is called by an `ngIf`.

Comment: this is over-optimization. as long as it is a boolean (and not a call to a complicated function) there is no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to keep the mindset of my original design without adding unnecessary new DOM elements, duplicating HTML code, or double-checking the same variable.

```
<div class="container">
    <ng-template *ngIf="booleanA;then caseA else caseB">
        <ng-template #caseA>
            <el>1</el>
            <el>2</el>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template #caseB>
            <ng-template *ngIf="booleanB;then caseC"></ng-template>
            <ng-template #caseC>
                <el>3</el>
                <el>4</el>
                <el>5</el>
            </ng-template>
        </ng-template>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

Thanks to everyone for giving me other paths to explore, those will serve me well.

Comment: Your angular tags are not working.  [Please refer here...](https://codesandbox.io/embed/angular-qg0po)

Answer (score 3):

Two changes you need to make

1. Using `ng-container`
2. Using `div` instead of nested `ng-template`

please see this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j3h3xn)

```
<div class="container">
    <ng-container *ngIf="booleanA; then caseA; else caseB">
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #caseA>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #caseB>
        <div *ngIf="booleanB">
            <span>3</span>
            <span>4</span>
            <span>5</span>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use ngSwitch:
https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch

example code from Angular:

```js
<container-element [ngSwitch]="switch_expression">
  <some-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_1">...</some-element>
  <some-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_2">...</some-element>
  <some-other-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_3">...</some-other-element>
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_3">
    <!-- use a ng-container to group multiple root nodes -->
    <inner-element></inner-element>
    <inner-other-element></inner-other-element>
  </ng-container>
  <some-element *ngSwitchDefault>...</some-element>
</container-element>
```